# Colombian citizen working for a small US company from abroad

Tags: united-states, taxes, working-abroad, colombia

I'm a Colombian citizen working as a consultant for a small US Company. 
I'm working from abroad (Colombia). My questions are:

1. What form does this US company need to fill out for taxes?
2. Can I pay for taxes in Colombia and not pay in the US? (I've been told that all I need is to show that I've paid them in my country)
3. Can the company pay me in a US bank account in US dollars?

Thankyou

Answer (score 2):

> What form does this US company need to fill out for taxes?

Nothing. *You* may need to provide to the company a form called W8-BEN to certify your foreign status.

> Can I pay for taxes in Colombia and not pay in the US? (I've been told
>   that all I need is to show that I've paid them in my country)

You don't need to show anything to anyone. You only pay taxes to the country you're resident of, Colombia.

> Can the company pay me in a US bank account in US dollars?

Technically they can, legally you'll have to check with a lawyer familiar with the Colombian law on the matter. Some countries restrict their citizens in handling foreign currency/accounts.